# Trying to stack lines closely in HTML

Tags: html, spacing

This should be simple, but I'm not getting it. I'm trying to get three lines (one small-font, one big, one small) to stack against each other with single-spacing. Instead, the big-font line always has a double-space above it (for 48-pt, there's a 48-pt line above it).

I've played with margins, padding, height, borders; I've stripped everything out but the bare essentials, and I still can't get the top and middle lines to lie nicely against each other.

Code:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<div style="
  font-size:16px; 
  height:16px;
  padding:0px;
  border:0px;
  margin:0px">
  <p>Line 1<p></div>

<div style="
  font-size:48px; 
  height:48px;
  padding:0px;
  border:0px;
  margin:0px">
  <p>Line 2</p></div>

<div style="
  font-size:16px; 
  height:16px;
  padding:0px;
  border:0px;
  margin:0px">
  <p>Line 3</p></font>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `p` tags they are unnecessary in the markup:

```
<div style="
  font-size:16px; 
  height:16px;
  padding:0px;
  border:0px;
  margin:0px">
  Line 1</div>

<div style="
  font-size:48px; 
  height:48px;
  padding:0px;
  border:0px;
  margin:0px">
  Line 2</div>

<div style="
  font-size:16px; 
  height:16px;
  padding:0px;
  border:0px;
  margin:0px">
  Line 3</div>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TSLA7/

If you absolutely need the `p` tags just remove their padding and margin:

```
p{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: BANG! You got it!

I didn't realize that the div tag created its own lines, like the p tag does.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let's keep things really simple here. What you are looking for is `line-height` and `margin`.

http://jsfiddle.net/TSLA7/1/

So, let's remove and simplify the html a little.

```
<div class='stacked_lines'>
    <div>
        <p>Line 1</p>
    </div>

    <div style="font-size:48px;">
        <p>Line 2</p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>Line 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in some CSS:

```
.stacked_lines div {
    line-height:1;
    font-size:16px;
}

.stacked_lines p {
    margin:0; 
}
```

So, we now didn't have to specify a height on the divs – they are `1` times the font size (i.e., the same as the font size!)

We have dropped the margin on the `p` elements, meaning they stack as needed.

Comment: This isn't a good solution, because p has margins defined for the other 99% of the instances in which it is used.

Comment: I'm assuming that you would use a class/id to narrow the selectors down, rather than do it exactly as specified here. In the example you gave, 100% of the `p`s were in `div`s :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use line-height instead to get rid of extra space between blobs.

```
p { 
    line-height:0.7;
    margin:0
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C4mFX/

Comment: No, the difference is not in using line-height; it's in applying it to p.

Try applying line-height to the div, and you'll see there's little-to-no difference.

Comment: it is line-height... I simply changed the p to div and it works exactly the same. You should use line-height because its a dynamic value. If you set all the values finitely as in your code your going to run into problems as the site scales -  especially with px. http://jsfiddle.net/C4mFX/